# space between a float left and float right

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[**This is the fiddle I'm messing around with**](http://jsfiddle.net/f6ba7/)

Is there a way to increase the space between what I have floating right and what's floating left? I just want to increase it 10px or something arbitrary like that, so I don't want to use width:20% Here's a pic for reference:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, all you have to do is specify a `margin` for the elements:

```
fieldset {
    float: left;
}
select {
    float: right;
    margin: 0 0 0 2em;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/f6ba7/1/).

Or:

```
fieldset {
    float: left;
}
fieldset label {
    margin: 0 1em 0 0;
}
select {
    float: right;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/f6ba7/5/).

Or, simply assign a `width` to the `fieldset` elements:

```
fieldset {
    float: left;
    width: 15em;
}
select {
    float: right;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/f6ba7/6/).